# Regex java. Why using intersection?

Tags: java, regex, intersection

I have taken from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) oracle tutorial on java regex, the following bit:

> Intersections
>
> To create a single character class matching only the characters common
>   to all of its nested classes, use &&, as in [0-9&&[345]]. This
>   particular intersection creates a single character class matching only
>   the numbers common to both character classes: 3, 4, and 5.
>
> Enter your regex: [0-9&&[345]] Enter input string to search: 3 I
>   found the text "3" starting at index 0 and ending at index 1.

Why would it be useful? I mean if one wants to pattern only **345** why not only [**345**] instead of "the intersection"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have two groups of numbers and you want to see if a given number is within both ranges, it would useful. Why wouldn't it be useful?

Comment: In this trivial case it's not useful. They're just giving a simple example of how intersection works. If you were _dynamically generating_ the regex then this might be useful. Otherwise, I typically find examples of the form `[0-9&&[^45]]` a more typical use case.

Answer (score 4):

Let us consider a simple problem: match English consonants in a string. Listing out all consonants (or a list of ranges) would be one way:

```
[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Zb-df-hj-np-tv-z]
```

Another way is to use look-around:

```
(?=[A-Za-z])[^AEIOUaeiou]
(?![AEIOUaeiou])[A-Za-z]
```

Not sure if there is any other way to do this without the use of character class intersection.

Character class intersection solution (Java):

```
[A-Za-z&&[^AEIOUaeiou]]
```

For .NET, there is no intersection, but there is character class subtraction:

```
[A-Za-z-[AEIOUaeiou]]
```

I don't know the implementation details, but I wouldn't be surprised if character class intersection/subtraction is faster than the use of look-around, which is the cleanest alternative if character class operation is not available.

Another possible usage is when you have a pre-built character class and you want to remove some characters from it. One case that I have come across where class intersection might be applicable would be to match all whitespace characters, except for new line.

Another possible use case as @beerbajay has commented:

> I think the built-in character classes are the main use case, e.g. `[\p{InGreek}&&\p{Ll}]` for lowercase Greek letters.

Comment: I think the built-in character classes are the main use case, e.g. `[\p{InGreek}&&\p{Ll}]` for lowercase greek letters.

Comment: @beerbajay: You are probably right. I have yet to run into that use case myself (Well, whether we runs into some use case or not depends on what we are doing).

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Character Classes".

Comment: I can't get `[A-Za-z&&[^AEIOUaeiou]]` working in RegexBuddy (Java or Perl flavors), or in Debuggex with any flavor. But in Java `Arrays.toString(Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z&&[^AEIOUaeiou]]").split("hello"))` is returning `[, e, , , o]` as expected.