# Understanding Regex expression

Tags: regex

I have a file where the application is configured to check the following Regex

```
[\x00-\x1F\x7F&&[^\x0A]&&[^\x0D]]
```

Can anyone please tell me the meaning of this regex expression exactly what it means. I do know that this regex expression ignored line feed and character feed. I even validated my file on http://regexr.com/ with the above specified regex expression and it shows no match found so not understanding why the regex is getting matched in the application.

FYI: I do not want the regex to match file as it is stopping my processing.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: The flavor used by RegExr doesn't support character-class intersection, so it interprets the ampersands in `&&` as literal ampersands, and it doesn't recognize the inner brackets as nested character classes.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that in Java and Ruby the regex expression `&&` refers to [character class intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930181/regex-java-why-using-intersection/15935168#15935168), while http://regexr.com/ doesn't support that expression and is trying to match literal `&` symbols. The regex you posted means match any characters from `\x00` to `\x1f` or `\x7f` as long as it's not `\x0A` or `\x0D`.